# How to access web-app through an Azure Application proxy with an access token

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-webapps

I have a web app configured in my Azure AD.
On a machine, i have installed a connector and configured an application proxy with that connector.

I am now trying to connect from an Android mobile application to the web app through the application proxy.

If I use a WebView inside my app, I can load the User access URL, enter my credentials and I receive a cookie for use by following connections.

I need to be able to use other HTTP clients that do not have the possibility to show UI.

I was wondering if it was possible to somehow request access and refresh tokens, and add those to future requests. or if possible convert them to a cookie in some manner and add that in a header.

Answer (score 0):

Your client app can simply use MSAL (or ADAL, or another OpenID Connect client library) to sign the user in and an access token *for the App Proxy app*. Then you can include that token in the `Authorization` header in requests to the endpoint from App Proxy. App Proxy will recognize it, validate it, and (if everything checks out) proxy the call down to the App Proxy connector, where the rest of the process happens as normal.

Here are the relevant docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-configure-native-client-application

Comment: the link you referenced is for native apps. i am trying to use a web app behind the proxy. how do i get a token for those with an OpenID library? what would be the redirect URI to give to the library (and token endpoint, scopes etc)? and would adding the tokens in the authorization header work?